# Compare Positions of Values in Php Array

Tags: php, arrays, position, compare, php-5.3

```
$commands = array();

    for($p = 0; $p < $commandCount ; $p++){
          $commands[$p] = $_POST['select'.$p];
    }
```

So I have this Array $commands. In this Array, a List of Commands is stored. I have to check on which Position the Command "mark" is stored and if a certain command follows after it.
Some Example Data which can be in $commands:
"mark", "ignore", "pick", "random"
 How would You do it?

Comment: Can you provide sample data stored in $commands?

Comment: "mark", "ignore", "pick", "random"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demonstration with a battery of test cases to fully express how it works and identify fringe cases:  ([Demo Link](https://3v4l.org/oi2Lp))

*note, `array_search()` returns `false` when the needle is not found.

```
$commands = array("mark", "ignore", "pick", "random");

$attempts = array("mark", "ignore", "pick", "random", "bonk");
foreach($attempts as $attempt){
    echo "$attempt => ";
    $index=array_search($attempt,$commands);
    //                                    vv---increment the value
    if($index===false || !isset($commands[++$index])){  // not found or found last element
        $index=0;                                      // use first element
    }
    echo $commands[$index],"\n";
}
```

The "or" (`||`) condition will "short circuit", so if `$index` is `false` it will exit the condition without calling the second expression (`isset()`).

Output:

```
mark => ignore
ignore => pick
pick => random
random => mark
bonk => mark
```

Comment: @mcv this is a demonstration of how I would do it... assuming the OP will want to default to the first value when the needle is either not found or the needle is the last element.

Comment: I have tested this out! This answer is actually the best one. Thanks for all your input. However if the needle is not found I would possibly use the choice that **value mark DNE**.

Comment: Yes, DNE may be a preferred output.  Only the OP can decide what is right for their application.

Comment: Unfortunately, my System is a little sensitive. But I managed to work my way around it. Now I hope I had every Opportunity in Mind.

Comment: @mickmackusa Sorry for my Late response I´ve been really busy. I was able to manage my Logic with array_search() I added a switch statement and got it to work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$index = array_search("mark", $commands)` which will return the index of the first occurrence of the command "mark" and then you can use `$commands[$index + 1]` to get the next command in the array.

You will also need to check if `$index != null` as otherwise it may return the first item in your `$commands` array because `null` is interpreted as 0

Comment: What would happen if my array would look like this? $command = array("mark","ignore","mark"?

Comment: It will return the position of the first "mark" element and the next will be "ignore"

Answer (score -1):

Just did some double checking you're going to want to assert first that your array contains the value of **mark** first. array_search will return a false otherwise, and that easily can be translated into 0.

Supporting Documentation :

[PHP in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

[PHP array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

```
$commands = array("mark", "ignore", "pick", "random");
//checks if $command contains mark, 
//gets first index as per documentation 
//Or sets index to -1, ie No such value exists.
 $index = in_array("mark",$commands) ? array_search("mark",$commands):-1;
//gets the next command if it exists
 $nextCommand = $index!=-1? $commands[++$index]:"Unable to Find Command: mark";
```

Comment: Performing `in_array()` then `array_search()` is not good programming.

Comment: Why not? You need to account for what if mark in not in the list of commands or  if `$commands = array("ignore", "pick", "random"); ` you will return the value of **pick** which makes all the answers above incorrect.

Comment: `array_search()` can do all of the necessary work.  `in_array()` is redundant array combing.  (not my downvote)

Comment: i just did that and got the answer above. I think you should double check this yourself.

Comment: I don't need to double check anything here.  Perhaps you should read the accepted answer.  I didn't downvote because it will return the desired outcome, it just isn't a professional grade answer.

Comment: No worries, but the accepted answer didn't have that null check when I read it. I just viewed the history and it was updated only 18 minutes ago. Some people are haters. I just provided an alternate way, and I learned something more by having this conversation with you. So thank you. :)

Comment: I'll be honest I don't like the mention of `null` in the answer, since it is more accurate to check for `false`.  I like your mentality.  You are never a "loser" if you are a "learner".  I have been a "learner" many, many times since joining this community.

Comment: @micmackusa Yeah I just checked the condition of where **mark** is the first option in `$commands` and, with a check of `!= false` OR `!= null` both returned the scenario it was not able to find the next command. How would you overcome this? Also the scenario where "mark" is the laast command was not considered in this question.

Comment: That is a "loose comparison"  it is vital when "falsey/zero-ish" values are possible that you perform a "strict comparison" like this: `===` or `!==`.